# Добавление в друзья и просмотр другого пользователя

Tags: php, mysql

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно организовать возможность добавления в друзья и просмотра страницы другого пользователя. Сама регистрация уже сделана. Может где есть статья... подскажите, буду очень благодарен!

Comment: Регистрация сделана ручками и головушкой или скачана с сети?

Comment: У самого такая же проблема. Только у меня сделано уже немного больше. Если хотите - посмотрите - http://vk.glazblog.ru логин www.ajaxs.ru пароль 12345

Comment: Ручками и головушкой))

Answer (score 1):

Не понимаю для чего изобретать велосипед, обратите внимание на готовые открытые системы, например [elgg](http://elgg.spb.ru/), [opensocial](http://code.google.com/intl/ru/apis/opensocial/) и т.п.